# Why i cant add Integer into generic collection at compile time itself eventhough the generics created with reference type as Number?

Tags: java

```
List<? super Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Number>();
List<? extends Number> integers2 = new ArrayList<Number>();
integers.add( new Integer(4));
integers2.add(new Integer(4));
```

I'm getting compiler error at last line, may i know why ?  even though ***Integer does extends Number*** im getting the following error

```
The method add(capture#3-of ? extends Number) in the type List<capture#3-of ? extends 
 Number> is not applicable for the arguments (Integer)
```

Comment: also interesting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `List<? extends Number>` is not a `List<Number>`.

`List<? extends Number>` could be, for example, a `List<Double>` or a `List<Float>`:

```
List<? extends Number> integers2 = new ArrayList<Double>(); //valid
```

It would not be valid to add an integer to a list of doubles, which is why the compiler prevents you from doing this.

You should probably not be using a wildcard (`?`) in this situation.

Comment: i totally get it , but why its throwing the error in compile time, it can also be an INTEGER right

Comment: this question has been asked and answered many times already. The usual course of action here is to close as duplicate rather than increase fragmentation of information

Comment: @TimCastelijns True enough. I don't know why I went straight into auto-answer mode. Because I have gold badge dupe close privileges, I've made this a community wiki so I don't get rep unfairly from the question no longer being open for new answers

Comment: @amarnathharish Java is all about pushing problem detection to compile time. Generics are a safe feature that was introduced to move related bug detection to compile time. Java does not wait for the actual type to show up at runtime, it detects that this **might** lead to an error and throws a compile time error. If you want a `List` that accepts all numbers, then write `List<Number>`. It is important to note that `? extends Number` does **not mean** *everything that extends is valid and can be mixed*. It is still locked to one single explicit type, defined by the caller.